# Interpreting PHP offline?

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn PHP, and it's getting annoying having to upload a file to the server every 30 seconds. Is there a way to get a browser (I use Chrome on Mac 10.6.7) to interpret a PHP file (browser plugin or external app)? Or, is there some way to "convert" the PHP to HTML, with all the "hypertext preprocessing" done?

In short, is there a way I can practice PHP without using a server, or installing a server on my computer?

Comment: I find the easiest way is to log in on your server and edit the PHP files locally. That way you do not have to upload.

Comment: How would I do that? I've been using FTP, and it's astoundingly slow.

Comment: 1) FTP is ancient. Not quite the same age as horse and cariagge, but really, avoid it.  2) Teh say I do it is by SSH-ing into the server and then editing the webpage/php files locally with vim (a texteditor).  Depending on your OS remete desktop or VNC are alternatives to ssh'ing to a shell).

Comment: @tkbx if you install a server on your home computer you won't have to deal with FTP or uploading at all. At that point it is just a drag and drop on the local filesystem.

Comment: @Moses I don't have root access to my machine, and I have a hosting package that I use for various things. `php` command will work for now. I've got a Linux install with LAMP as well, but it's being used for something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really no, "PHP is an open source server-side scripting language designed for Web development to produce dynamic Web pages". You could just set up a local server and test there, that is what I do.

Alternatively, on Linux at least, you *can* run PHP scripts from the command line:

```
$ php index.php > output.html
```

You can then open the resulting html in a web browser.

Comment: This also works on OS X since, for example Mountain Lion, ships with PHP 5.3.15. Or If the OP wants to install a server nonetheless, [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) would be a good solution since it's rather isolated from the OS and can be removed easily.

Comment: I've got Snow Leopard, and I've got `php`. This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: You can run php from the command line under windows as well, just saying

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I never said you couldn't. I just said you could on Linux which is the OS I use. I'm sure other OSs can also do it but I don't know the syntax or anything about it so I didn't mention them.

Comment: Using PHP built-in web server consumes far less resources than a LAMP, MAMP, XAMP, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. PHP already has a built-in web server. Here is how you start it.

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

The terminal or command window will show:

```
PHP 5.4.0 Development Server started at Thu Jul 21 10:43:28 2011
Listening on localhost:8000
Document root is ~/public_html
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

Now open your web browser to: http://localhost:8000

Answer (score -1):

Just install MAMP, you can run php local on your computer.
http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: I've tried various AMP stacks for Mac, and they all need root/admin, which I don't have. I'll try that one, but the `php` program has worked well so far (other than GET and POST.)

Comment: have you tried Uniserver you can run it on a flash drive, full Apache php mysql

Comment: Using PHP built-in web server consumes far less resources than a LAMP, MAMP, XAMP, etc...